# SingleChildScrollView error "RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded"

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make the content of a `Container` scrollable, and I think that I probably mis-use the `SingleChildScrollView` widget.

Is it okay to put it **inside** of a `Container` (as its child) because I want its content to be scrollable ?

Thanks.

```
Hero(
            tag: this.widget.id,
            child: Material(
              type: MaterialType.transparency,
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                  decoration: cardDecoration,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(

                    child: ContentTripExtract(this.widget.i, false) // a column of texts and containers
                    ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that the **SingleChildScrollView** has only **one child** like this:

```
 child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
```

And don't Use flex in the child views.
In your case, I think it works

```
child: SingleChildScrollView(
child: Container(
child: ContentTripExtract(this.widget.i, false) // a column of texts and containers
  ),
```